# How do I find the joint pdf of bivariate normal distribution from scratch given linear correlation coefficient and their marginal distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

I'm taking a stat class and the professor just wrote down the joint pdf of a bivariate normal distribution, even though the pdf looks "intuitive" but I'm not able to derive the formula for the same.

I'm unsure of where I even start.

Here's what it looks like :

$$
f(x, y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_x\sigma_y\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[\frac{(x - \mu_x)^2}{\sigma_x^2} - 2\rho\frac{(x - \mu_x)(y - \mu_y)}{\sigma_x\sigma_y} + \frac{(y - \mu_y)^2}{\sigma_y^2}\right]\right)
$$

Where do I start given I know :

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma_x\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x - \mu_x)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\right)
$$

$$
f(y) = \frac{1}{\sigma_y\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{(y - \mu_y)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}\right)
$$

and

$$\rho = \frac{\text{Cov}(X, Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}
$$

Comment: Hint: 

Let $Z_1,Z_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$  be independent standard normal random variables, and use the transformation

$$X= \mu_x + \sigma_xu_1(Z_1,Z_2) = \mu_x + \sigma_xZ_1 ,\quad Y = \mu_y + \sigma_y u_2(Z_1,Z_2) = \mu_y + \sigma_y\left[\rho Z_1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_2\right]$$

Comment: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/23/23.1